# MariaDB with Heidisql JSON_REMOVE not working

Tags: mariadb, heidisql

i try to execute following statement on my heidisql mariadb db:

```
UPDATE users SET inventory=JSON_REMOVE(inventory,'$.spray');
```

it already worked on phpmyadmin on other databases, but not here.

I get the following error:

[image]

someone knows about this ?
Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What versions of HeidiSQL and MariaDB ? ... also do you have a example data?

Answer (score 0):

The error complains about "argument 1", which is the `users`.`inventory` column in your case. Means you have some invalid JSON code, in one or more rows of your `users` table. You have to find and fix that invalid JSON in the table, probably by scrolling through HeidiSQL's data tab result.

By the way, I can only reproduce the error on MySQL 5.7, not on MariaDB 10.3 or 10.5.

*Edit: you may find the invalid rows easily, with such a query:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE NOT JSON_VALID(`inventory`);
```